# What is the distribution of the stopping time for Brownian motion with two barriers?

Tags: probability-distributions

The distribution for the stopping time of Brownian motion with one barrier is well known. There is also the formula for the expectation AB, where A and -B are the barriers, A,B bigger than 0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I found a reference, you can delete the question.